# IMAP SEARCH complex query

Tags: imap, gmail-imap

I need to find all mails in IMAP mailbox which contains `somestring` in BODY and is FROM `someone@me.com` or TO `someone@me.com`.

Trying to do:

```
49:51.53 > JBPM3 SEARCH CHARSET utf-8 "BODY \"somestring\" (OR (TO \"someone@me.com\") (FROM \"someone@me.com\"))"
```

Receiving:

```
49:51.71 < JBPM3 BAD Could not parse command
```

How to make it work using GMail?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may skip parenthesis '(' ')' to group logical expressions in IMAP.
Parenthesis are not needed in Polish Notation (see edit below):

```
A0001 SEARCH CHARSET utf-8 BODY "somestring" OR TO "someone@me.com" FROM "someone@me.com"
```

You could also use gmail search syntax (X-GM-RAW) command: 
http://www.limilabs.com/blog/search-gmail-using-gmails-search-syntax

[Edit]
Parenthesis are sometimes required in IMAP SEARCH. This is because AND operator can have more than 2 operands and is not explicitly defined:
http://www.limilabs.com/blog/imap-search-requires-parentheses

Comment: Just a quick correction - IMAP does not use reverse polish notation (which would be more like: `"somestring" BODY "someone@me.com" TO "someone@me.com" FROM OR AND`) but simply polish (or prefix) notation.  IMAP's design is based on LISP, from what I can gather.